# how can you don't replace a value in an array when you are replacing the value with nothing in python?

Tags: python, arrays, replace, sympy, python-re

```
import sympy as sp
import math
import re

a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z = sp.symbols('a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z') 

formula = input('')
unknown_values = int(input('how many unknown values?: '))

unknown_array = []
values = []

for i in range(unknown_values):
    unknown_name = input('unknown value: ')
    unknown_array += [unknown_name]

for i in range(len(unknown_array)):
    values += [input('Enter the value of ' + unknown_array[i] + ': ')]

for word in unknown_array:
    formula = formula.replace(word, values[unknown_array.index(word)])


formula = re.split(r'[=|<|>|<=|>=|==]', formula)[0:2]
split_a = sympify(formula[0])
split_b = sympify(formula[1])
split_c = simplify(split_a - split_b)
result = sp.solve(split_c, x)

for w in result:
    print(w.evalf())
```

input: a*x**2 + b*x + c = 0

how many unknown values?: 3

unknown value: a

unknown value: b

unknown value: c

Enter the value of a: 1

Enter the value of b: 5

Enter the value of c: 6

-3.00000000000000

-2.00000000000000

this is how my code works. But when I put the values in 'unknown_array', i need to put only a,b,c and not x because it's the one I need to find. I would like to put also x in 'unknown_array' and in 'values' nothing (just press enter). The problem is that if I put nothing, then, when it will replace the values, it will just eliminate x. So I would like that in every value that I just press enter, it won't replace that value and put that value here: result = sp.solve(split_c, ...); instead of the 3 points and so solve for that value. While if there are multiple values, it will solve them one at a time and print every result.

Comment: so, you don't want the values list you have created, you just want to use unknown_array named list?

Comment: no I want the value list, but in every value that I press enter, it won't replace it and put in result = sp.solve(split_c, ...) instead of the tree points. If the values to find are more, then it will solve onee by one and print every result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing things with strings that you don't have to but if you want to reinvent the wheel that is always a way to learn so I won't try change the code. But as for how to solve for something other than `x` you need to identify what variable is left. You could do that by having the user identify what they are going to supply values for and then just don't say that you are solving for `x`:

```
sp.solve(split_c) instead of sp.solve(split_c, x)
```

This will return a dictionary with the solved value.

Otherwise, if you have an expression like `a*x+b` and they say there are 3 unknowns and they want to "press return" on the one they want to solve for then when it comes to substituting in values, just skip that one during replacement (or replace it with the corresponding symbol):

```
for word in unknown_array:
    i = unknown_array.index(word)
    formula = formula.replace(word, values[i] or unknown_array[i])
```

And then, again, don't pass `x` to `solve` -- `solve` will work it out if there is one symbol left.

Comment: It should work out any symbol. It will select one of the unknowns that it can solve for if you don't provide any. I would need a specific example to give a more specific answer.

Comment: This is what happens when I run the code: (a/b) * (d/c) = 1
how many unknown values?: 4
unknown value: a
unknown value: b
unknown value: c
unknown value: d
This is the equation simplified: 0
Enter the value of a: 4
Enter the value of b: 2
Enter the value of c: 6
Enter the value of d: (I press enter and afterwards it just doesn't print the answers)

Comment: I get [3] with the code here: https://gist.github.com/smichr/dbc712b6d6c89a9b827e8ba019b75d11